# Azure sql server firewall rule for IPv6

Tags: sql-server, azure, firewall, ipv6

I want to allow the **complete** range of IPv6 on an Azure SQL-server.
The code in Azure Cli I use is:
az sql server ipv6-firewall-rule create --name --resource-group --server --start-ipv6-address 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 --end-ipv6-address ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff

I get the error "(IPv6EndpointDisabled) The IPv6 endpoint is not allowed because it is disabled".

so question is: what is the allowed range for IPV6 on sql-server?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the issue in my environment with below command:

```
az sql server ipv6-firewall-rule create --name <name> --resource-group <resourcegroupName>  --server <serverName> --start-ipv6-address 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 --end-ipv6-address ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

Firewall rule created without any error:

[image]

To list the firewall rules, I executed below command.

```
az sql server ipv6-firewall-rule list -g <resourcegroupName> -s <serverName>
```

[image]

> what is the allowed range for IPV6 on sql-server?

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/ipv6-overview) IPV6 is not supported by Azure sql server.

[image]

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/connecting-using-ipv6?view=sql-iserver-ver16) It only supports for sql server.

[image]

You should use IPV4 firewall rule to connect Azure sql server. You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure?view=azuresql) for more information.